# Windows 7 Gadgets broken/missing

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

First off, this is not a dupe of this question:  [Windows 7 - gadgets disappeared](https://superuser.com/questions/272355/windows-7-gadgets-disappeared)

My Gadgets disappeared from my desktop.  When I right-click on the desktop and then Gadgets to attempt to bring them back, nothing happens.  I can't even select any Gadget options under `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization`.  Doing so results in nothing happening yet again.  I just noticed this a few days ago and do not know what changes I could have made that would cause this to happen.

Comment: I know I should comment this, but I don't have 50 rep points yet, so please don't downvote this because it's not technically an answer. <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/gadgets">Microsoft discontinued gadgets</a> quite some time ago on all current and future version of Windows. I don't know if that would necessarily cause this problem as it looks like existing gadgets would still work, but I figured it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Have you tried doing the steps suggested in [old question](http://superuser.com/questions/272355/windows-7-gadgets-disappeared). How is it different from that question?

Comment: It looks  like this question belongs to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open task-manager (Ctrl+Alt+Del) and then click on "File -> Run new Task" and add "sidebar.exe" and then see what happens. If your gadgets return to normal or rather try that .bat file from [Windows 7 - gadgets disappeared](https://superuser.com/questions/272355/windows-7-gadgets-disappeared) from Kyle's answer, as that .bat file can recover each and every gadget files to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem for me by killing the `sidebar.exe` process. After this, selecting "Gadgets" from the desktop right-click menu restored the gadgets.